# open jupyter notebook file in linux from folder system

Tags: jupyter, linux

I have .ipynb files stored locally on my computer. The way I currently open these is by opening the terminal, typing "jupyter notebook" then navigating through jupyter notebook's file system to my .ipynb file.

It would be nice if I can just double click the .ipynb file in ubuntu's native file system and have it automatically open jupyter notebook with that file in my browser. Is this possible?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/848350/how-to-handle-jupyter-notebook-files-in-ubuntu